# What's the recommended way to connect to Amazon MemoryDB for Redis programmatically?

Tags: redis, jedis, elastic-cache, amazon-memory-db, py-redis

I'm new to Redis and Amazon MemoryDB.
Currently I'm able to spin up a Redis Cluster using Amazon MemoryDB, following the [aws document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/memorydb/latest/devguide/getting-startedclusters.connecttonode.html).

`redis-cli` works for me to link to my redis cluster (from another EC2 instance inside of the VPC):

```
>> redis-cli -c --tls -h my-redis-cluster.idocmu.memorydb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com -p 6379
my-redis-cluster.idocmu.memorydb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:6379> PING
PONG
```

When I tried to connect to it using python/Java in the same EC2 instance, connections never work:

```
>> python3
Python 3.7.16 (default, Dec 15 2022, 23:24:54) 
[GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.RedisCluster(host="my-redis-cluster.idocmu.memorydb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", port=6379)

... python3 fronzen here...
```

The same for Jedis the Java Client:

```
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("my-redis-cluster.idocmu.memorydb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", 6379);
jedis.set("key100", "value100");

... java connection timeout here...
```

Is there something I missed?
Why redis-cli is able to connect while my scripts cannot?

Also tried some other clients listed in Redis page:
https://redis.io/resources/clients/
Redission also failed to connect.
It seems something must be wrong with my setup. But I just cannot understand why redis-cli is able to connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because when you connect with `recis-cli`, you provide `--tls` (means your cluster is configured with in-transit encryption).

However when you connect with the other clients, you don't use TLS. In order to connect with `redis-py` for example, you need to provide `ssl=True`:

```
redis.RedisCluster(host="my-redis-cluster.idocmu.memorydb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", port=6379, ssl=True)
```

See examples [here](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/ssl_connection_examples.html).